# Printing a function drawing next to each other

Tags: c

I was wondering how I could print multiple rockets (based on scanf input) next to each other, I can use a for loop to print them underneath one another but I need it to output it next to each other and am at a loss on how I could do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rocket_ship(void);

int main(void)
{
    int number_of_rockets=0;
    printf("Prepare how many rockets for launch? ");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_rockets);


for (int rockets=0;rockets<number_of_rockets;rockets++)
   {
    rocket_ship();
   }
}

void rocket_ship(void)
{
    printf("   /\\\n");
    printf("  /  \\\n");
    printf(" /    \\\n");
    printf("+------+\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("+------+\n");
    printf("|N     |\n");
    printf("|     Z|\n");
    printf("|Rocket|\n");
    printf("+------+\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("|      |\n");
    printf("+------+\n");
    printf("   /\\\n");
    printf("  /  \\\n");
    printf(" /    \\\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
void rocket_ship(int number)
{
    for (int i=0; i<number ++i)
    {
               printf("   /\\   ");
    }
    printf("\n");
    
    // And similar for all the next lines
```

Comment: Is there not another way? Seems extremely tedious.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi There are many other ways but this is likely to the simplest.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi If you want ultimate control and more complex code - go for `ncurses`

Comment: Probably for the best lol, this is for a beginners programming course was just trying to figure out how it could be done in prep for exams.

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi I have no idea what your last comment is supposed to mean. But good luck with the exam

Comment: @UltraInstinctMessi you can define picture as tata and then have generic function to print the way you want

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *rocket[] =
{
"   /\\   ",
"  /  \\  ",
" /    \\ ",
"+------+",
"|      |",
"|      |",
"|      |",
"+------+",
"|N     |",
"|     Z|",
"|Rocket|",
"+------+",
"|      |",
"|      |",
"|      |",
"+------+",
"   /\\   ",
"  /  \\  ",
" /    \\ ",
NULL,
};

void print(const char **picture, const char *delim, int repeat)
{
    while(*picture)
    {
        for(int pic = 0; pic < repeat; pic++)
        {
            printf("%s%s", *picture, pic == repeat - 1 ? "" : delim);
        }
        printf("\n");
        picture++;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    print(rocket, "  |  ", 3);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hK749n